# HERE Geocoding API returns wrong result in AT only by minor changes in streetname

Tags: here-api

We noticed a strange behaviour with the Geocoding API.
The address we are trying to geocode is: "Prof.-Wirtinger-Straße 16" in "Ybbs an der Donau" with zipcode 3370 in Austria.

HERE Geocoding API returns:

```
lat=48.17875, lon=15.0814,
country=AT,
area1=Niederösterreich,
locality=Ybbs an der Donau,
zip=3370,
subLocality1=Ybbs an der Donau,
street=Professor-Wirtinger-Gasse,
streetNumber=16
```

When changing the streetname to "Prof. Wirtingerstraße 16", which means only a few changes in spelling, the first result is:

```
lat=48.27188, lon=14.40943,
country=AT,
area1=Oberösterreich,
locality=Luftenberg an der Donau,
zip=4225,
subLocality1=Luftenberg,
street=Alte Straße,
streetNumber=12
```

So this result is about 50 km away from the right address and apart from "an der Donau", almost nothing is right here.

How can we deal with such results? Recommendations to identify this? Other ideas?

---

*edit/additional info:*

We used the qualified geocoding request with parampeters country, postalCode, city and street and url https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode? as described here https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html
Our goal is to verify or correct more or less complete addresses.
The requests for the addresses in the question are:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=country=Österreich;postalCode=3370;city=Ybbs an der Donau;street=Prof.-Wirtinger-Straße 16&lang=de
```

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=country=Österreich;postalCode=3370;city=Ybbs an der Donau;street=Prof. Wirtingerstraße 16&lang=de
```

We are able to reproduce the above behaviour with other addresses too and it seems the street "Alte Straße" is a kind of fallback if HERE doesn´t know the street. All of the following requests returns street "Alte Straße" as resolved streetname in the first address result.
Examples:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=country=Germany;postalCode=04357;city=Leipzig;street=Dounder Straße 8&lang=de (typo in streetname, which should be Dortmunder Straße)
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=country=Germany;postalCode=26180;city=Oldenburg;street=Memelstraße 8&lang=de (street Memelstraße 8 is wrong in Oldenburg, but exists in city Rastede near Oldenburg)
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=country=Germany;postalCode=35041;city=Marburg;street=Wehraerstraße 10&lang=de (typo in streetname, which should be Wehrdaer Straße)
```

We expect as response for example no address result or an address of resultType locality / administrativeArea without a streetname.

Answer (score 0):

The q parameter is to be used to submit the growing phrases, one Autosuggest query per additional key-stroke.

For instance when an end-user interacts with the application, he/she might intend to enter the letters r, e, s, t, a, u, r, a, n, t. The application would then send a request with a q parameter set to "r", then "re", "res", "rest", etc. The customer can decide to send Autosuggest queries starting with the first key-stroke in order to provide very early suggestions. It can also be decided to only send queries starting with the 3rd key stroke. The example queries would then have a q set to "res", "rest", etc.

It would be helpful if you can share the exact API that has been used at your end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added more details in the question above.